# Can I remove Snap folders on Ubuntu Focal 20.04?

Tags: snap, directory, software-uninstall

I have the below on my Ubuntu 20.04:

```
/dev/loop1 303488 303488 0 100% /snap/google-cloud-cli/40

/dev/loop2 304384 304384 0 100% /snap/google-cloud-cli/42

/dev/loop0 56960 56960 0 100% /snap/core18/2409

/dev/loop3 45824 45824 0 100% /snap/snapd/15904

/dev/loop4 48128 48128 0 100% /snap/snapd/16010
```

I'm supposing that these filesystems were installing after I installed google-cloud-cli through snap.

I removed the below

```
root:~# sudo apt-get remove google-cloud-cli

root:~# sudo apt autoremove
```

When I restarted my system, the five `/dev/loop*` file systems were still there consuming my space.

Can I remove them? if yes, how can I do so safely??

Thank you!

Comment: Those filesystems are for a snap package. The bottom three are fine, they are just for Snap. The top two would be probably for a Google Cloud CLI snap app. But... you would uninstall the Snap one. The `apt` version will have no effect there

Comment: Thank you guys for your valuable feedback: Really the community is the gas driving the adoption of Ubuntu!! I removed google cloud cli with root@habiboto:~# snap remove google-cloud-cli
root@habiboto:~# snap list --all  root@habiboto:~# snap list --all
Name    Version   Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes
core18  20220428  2409   latest/stable  canonical✓  base
snapd   2.55.5    15904  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd,disabled
snapd   2.56      16010  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
  Shall I keep the other snap packages (and FS) or delete them as well??